# UPDATE command SET @return = [int_a] = [int_a] + auto_increment WHERE <clause>

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a lot of C# programs and SQL stored procs that call one horribly written SQL stored proc (320+ lines containing lots of similar IF's that have been copied & pasted for years) that I need to finally clean up and speed up.

Notes:

- This stored proc is executed 1,000's of times per hour.
- This question is about this stored proc, not how it is referenced or changing references.

We have a table with this structure:

- type (VARCHAR)
- last updated (DATETIME)
- counter (INT)
- auto_increment flag (INT, either 0 or 1)

(i.e.: an incrementing customer # 123456, and a non-incrementing billing cycle # 1001)

When executed for:

- customer #: increment 123456 to 123457, last_updated = now, & return new 123457.
- billing cycle: the value 1001 is returned.

My boss wants **only one command that hits the table**. I've managed to accomplish that with this snippet:

```
DECLARE
    @return_value INT,
    @parmtype VARCHAR(10),

SET @parmtype = 'CUSTOMER'

UPDATE [system_numbers]                  -- 1 hit
SET @return_value = current_number = current_number + auto_increment,
    last_updated_on = 
        CASE auto_increment
            WHEN 1 THEN GETDATE()
            ELSE last_updated_on
        END
    WHERE [type] = @parmtype
```

My problem is that for the non-incrementing [type]'s, my command needlessly updates the table, writes to the log, and is slower than a SELECT.

My question is ... **what one command can I use that removes this example's two hits to the table?**

```
DECLARE
    @return_value INT,                    -- actually an OUTPUT param in my SP
    @autoincrement INT,
    @parmtype VARCHAR(10)

SET @parmtype = 'CUSTOMER'

SELECT @autoincrement = auto_increment    -- 1st hit
FROM [system_numbers]
WHERE [type] = @parmtype

IF (@autoincrement = 1)
BEGIN
    UPDATE [system_numbers]               -- 2nd hit here - or -
    SET @return_value = current_number = current_number + auto_increment,
        last_updated_on = GETDATE()
        WHERE [type] = @parmtype
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @return_value = current_number -- 2nd hit here
    FROM [system_numbers]
    WHERE [type] = @parmtype
END
```

Comment: Be careful with forcing assumptions where they don't apply. A 320 line stored proc with lots of copypasta IFs doesn't necessarily mean it's badly written.  SQL is not a pretty language, and sometimes the best solution includes a bunch of redundant-looking code.

Comment: Our SP has 1 input parameter with 24 `IF LOWER(@param) = 'value'` commands. No `ELSE`'s.

`IF LOWER(@param)='a'  BEGIN  SELECT 'x'... END`
`IF LOWER(@param)='b'  BEGIN  SELECT 'y'... END`
`IF LOWER(@param)='c'  BEGIN  SELECT 'z'... END`

Every `IF` runs & lowers @param's value. Picky but users complain about speed. If only this SP had `SET @param = LOWER(@param) ` & 24 "ranked" `IF`'s based on the most frequently passed values and a bunch of `ELSE ` commands. Harder to follow code but it would execute faster.  The @param's value is not used in the `UPDATE ` or `SELECT ` commands.

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong thing.  Removing the `LOWER()` calls won't change a thing since the server still has to do them implicitly when comparing strings (assuming you are using the default collation--or any other case-insensitive collation).  You will see zero improvement in performance.  (also, `LOWER()` is so cheap there is zero chance that's your bottleneck)

Comment: My focus is my original question ... what one command can I use that removes this example's two hits to the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably consider the following approach:

```
...

UPDATE dbo.system_numbers
SET @return_value = current_number = current_number + auto_increment,
    last_updated_on = GETDATE()
WHERE [type] = @parmtype
  AND auto_increment = 1
;
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
  SELECT @return_value = current_number
  FROM dbo.system_numbers
  WHERE [type] = @parmtype
;
```

The first statement updates the value only if it happens to be an incrementing one, and also stores the updated value in `@return_value`.

The second statement only executes if the first statement did not update any row. It just assigns the (current) value to `@return_value`.

So, this is one hit only when the value is an incrementing one. When it is non-incrementing, a second hit is involved, but in that case also nothing gets updated, only read.

Comment: Impressive! I use `@@ROWCOUNT` all the time and can't believe I did not think of using it. While I test your code in our world, would you mind commenting about your preference for `<> 0` over `= 1` in your `UPDATE` command? I ask because my preference would have been `= 1`. FYI, this rarely edited table (within SSMS) has 30-ish rows and `auto_increment` values are always 0 or 1.

Comment: Ah, if it's never going to be a different increment, then I would certainly use `= 1`. I only meant to account for possible future changes to that column. I'll just update my answer to `= 1` then.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would simplify things a bit

```
DECLARE
@return_value INT,                    -- actually an OUTPUT param in my SP
@autoincrement INT,
@parmtype VARCHAR(10)

SET @parmtype = 'CUSTOMER'

SELECT @autoincrement = auto_increment, @return_value = auto_increment + current_number    -- 1st hit
FROM [system_numbers]
WHERE [type] = UPPER(@parmtype)

IF (@autoincrement = 1)
BEGIN
UPDATE [system_numbers]               -- 2nd hit here - or -
SET current_number = @return_value,
    last_updated_on = GETDATE()
    WHERE [type] = UPPER(@parmtype)
END
```

Comment: Thanks. That is cleaner than my code and I like it. However, my boss says one hit to the table. I've considered using this as a way to separate the UPDATE and SELECT commands:

    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM [system_numbers]
        WHERE [type] = UPPER(@parmtype)
        AND auto_increment = 1
    )

Sigh. How do I get code to format as code in here?

Comment: -1 What happens if the table data changes between your two statements?

Comment: @Anon, please, provide an answer to my question. Thank you.

Comment: @Anon it's all in one transaction.

Answer (score 0):

We decided that the IF EXISTS( ) command is fast and works for our needs.

A bonus to that is if it returns true, we know @parmtype is auto-incrementing and we no longer need the variable @autoincrement which results in even cleaner code.

```
DECLARE
    @return_value INT,       -- OUTPUT param
    @parmtype VARCHAR(10)

SET @parmtype = 'CUSTOMER'

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [type]=@parmtype AND auto_increment=1 )
BEGIN
    UPDATE [table]
    SET @return_value = current_number = current_number + auto_increment,
        last_updated_on = GETDATE()
    WHERE [type] = @parmtype
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @return_value = current_number
    FROM [table]
    WHERE [type] = @parmtype
END
```

Comment: I hope you realise that you are still hitting the table twice.

Comment: Yes, I realize that my answer hits the table twice. Please add a one-hit answer and I'll select it as the answer.